# Equivalent useMemo async function?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-usememo

I need to make a HEAVY (needs .then() syntax) API call only ONCE in my app. What I have works, using useState and useEffect, but when the context reloads, it makes the API call again.

Is there a way to rewrite this to work using useMemo, so if the context re-renders, it can use the saved response instead of making the API call again?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fetchData from 'utils/fetchData';

export MyContext = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchData().then(res=> setData(res));
  },[]);

  return(
    {/*... */}
  );
}
```

I tried these separately to no avail...

```
const response = useMemo(async () => await fetchData(),[]);
const response = useMemo(() => fetchData(), []);
const response = useMemo(fetchData(), []);

// Also separately tried in fetchData.js...
export default React.memo(fetchData);
```

Comment: When you say re-render, I assume you mean re-mounted? Cos your `useEffect` has no dependencies so only executes once, on mount. Only way to get it to run again is to re-mount the component. That being, either lift the fetching logic into a higher component that isn't re-mounted, os just put this API request into a React context and connect components that need it

Comment: Maybe lift the state higher up the tree to where it does not get recreated. `useMemo` recalculates the same way `useEffect` gets called, the dependency array. If `useEffect` is   running multiple times so would a `useMemo` with the same dependency array. As your dependency array contains nothing and is only run on mount of the component your issue is either A) Why is your context component being destroyed and mounted again? or B) Is this the appropriate location to store the state, or should it be lifted up your component tree?